# Is there any trick to forbid C macro to be called as a lvalue?

Tags: c, macros

For example,

```
struct node {
  struct node *left, *right;
};
#define LEFT(X) (X->left)
#define RIGHT(X) (X->right)
```

I would like to forbid macro call like this without changing the existing macro interface.

```
LEFT(n) = ...
```

Any idea?

Comment: What does that macro do? I don't understand why you would ever need a macro like that.

Comment: @Lundin I take it as example. for real code there're a lot of deep-structed members, accessor-macros will be useful.

Comment: @wsxiaoys Ok I see. I will post an answer with an example of how you should do such macros.

Comment: Why did you remove [c++]? Now my answer does not apply anymore... I will keep it because the original question said it is a C++ question too.

Comment: @Johannes: Often it means the OP was interested in C answers but added the `c++` tag in hopes of getting more exposure/attention... :-)

Comment: I definitely find `X->left->right` easier to read than `RIGHT(LEFT(X))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
#define LEFT(X) ((X)->left+0)
#define RIGHT(X) ((X)->right+0)
```

Comment: This looks like the most simple one, but it may not be optimized like ternary operator I guess.

Comment: Wow !! ... simple yet efffective

Comment: @wsxiaoys: Don't you really thing that a constant addition of `0` is more difficult that pruning a branch never taken ? If anything it is definitely simpler!

Comment: @Matthieu I just made an assumption that ternary operator like "1?xx:xx" will be easier to recognize by the compiler who perform the optimization

Comment: @wsxiaoys: well, be assured, I tried it out, and the `+0` is absent from the assembly using llvm-gcc. I do prefer Alexey's solution though, better use functions that macros when possible.

Comment: Of course the +0 is absent from the assembly. It would take a maliciously bad compiler to generate code for it.

Answer (score 6):

```
#undef LEFT
#undef RIGHT

//template<class T>
inline const node * const LEFT(const node * X) {
    return X->left;
}
```

Comment: Kinda smarmy, but +1.  The best advice is to not use macros at all.

Comment: @wsxiaoys You can also create inline functions in C99.

Comment: @Jesper: you can, although they won't be generic like the macro is or like a template could be in C++. That may or may not be required here.

Answer (score 5):

I'd go with the inline function, but if you want a macro:

```
#define LEFT(X) (1 ? (X)->left : 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is any way of preventing that. Probably the best way would be not to use macros.

Comment: This is the proper solution to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the ternary operator to force the result of the macro to be an rvalue, but the error message might be confusing to users:

```
struct node {
   node *left, *right;
};
#define LEFT( x ) ( true ? (x).left : (node*)0 )
int main() {
   node n;
   // LEFT( n ); // error
   node *l = LEFT( n ); // OK
}
```

The trickery there is in the semantics of that specific operator. The type of the expression containing just the operator is a common type (or a type convertible from) of the two branches of the expression, even if only one of them is ever evaluated. Now, when the compiler evaluates `true ? x.left : (node*)0` it resolves to the expression `x.left` but with the common type of `x.left` and `(node*)0`. Both of them are basically the same type, with the only detail that `(node*)0` is an rvalue, rather than a lvalue.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `const`, though it requires an explicit type:

```
#define LEFT(X) ((const struct node *) (X->left))
```

...though if you have the `typeof` compiler extension:

```
#define LEFT(X) ((const typeof(X->left)) (X->left))
```

Comment: These are still lvalues. OP is trying to make it impossible to edit the pointer, not the data it points to.

Answer (score 1):

For C++, I would use unary +:

```
#define LEFT(X) (+((X)->left))
#define RIGHT(X) (+((X)->right))
```

For a general macro case, this has the advantage over adding `+0` that it also works for `void*` and function pointers. For C, you can use the comma operator

```
#define LEFT(X) (0, ((X)->left))
#define RIGHT(X) (0, ((X)->right))
```

Comment: In general, this is better than my answer since it also works for `void *`. For OP's problem it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Finally I adding `+0` in my code because using comma operator this way generate a lot of "Expression result unused" warning

Comment: @wsxiaoys: Possibly casting to `void` as
`#define LEFT(X) ((void)0, ((X)->left))`
may suppress the warning.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just go for an explicit cast

```
#define LEFT(X) ((struct node*)(X->left))
#define RIGHT(X) ((struct node*)(X->right))
```

the result of such a cast is always an rvalue. If in addition you don't want to allow to change what the pointers are pointing to add a `const` as was already given in another answer:

```
#define LEFT(X) ((struct node const*)(X->left))
#define RIGHT(X) ((struct node const*)(X->right))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't write "accessor" macros like that, you do

```
typedef struct
{
  ...
} X;

X x;

#define LEFT (x.y.z.left)
```

Then you access the LEFT macro like any other variable. This makes the code more readable while at the same time effectively disabling the whole unsafe, ugly-looking, error prone, undefined-behavior ballet associated with function-like macros.